# Shouldn't `randperm` in the PyTorch C++ API return a tensor with default type int?

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

When I try to generate a list of permuted integer indices with `randperm` using the C++ PyTorch API, the resulting tensor has the element type of `CPUFloatType{10}` instead of an integer type:

```
int N_SAMPLES = 10;               
torch::Tensor shuffled_indices = torch::randperm(N_SAMPLES); 
cout << shuffled_indices << endl;
```

returns

```
 9
 3
 8
 6
 2
 5
 4
 7
 1
 0
[ CPUFloatType{10} ]
```

Which cannot be used used for indexing of tensors because the element type is float and not an integer type. When tryig to use `my_tensor.index(shuffled_indices)` I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::IndexError'
  what():  tensors used as indices must be long, byte or bool tensors
```

Environment:

- python-pytorch, version 1.6.0-2 on Arch Linux
- g++ (GCC) 10.1.0

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the default type of any tensor that you create with torch is always `float`. If you want otherwise, you have to specify it with the `TensorOptions` parameter struct :

```
int N_SAMPLES = 10;               
torch::Tensor shuffled_indices = torch::randperm(N_SAMPLES, torch::TensorOptions().dtype(at::kLong));
cout << shuffled_indices.dtype() << endl;
>>> long
```